# wget/curl download a file

Tags: curl, wget

I have the following problem. I would like to download a text from the following link:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_021206.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text

I've tried with both `wget` and `curl` but instead of downloading the text file they download an html page. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: It uses Javascript to generate the text in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that server does not return real text file, but rather a script, that generates it on a client side. I guess, it's a protective measure from automatic leaching scripts, like the one you are trying to create.

But, on the other hand, it's quite lame measure, because they are loading the text they want to protect from another URL, in your case its:

```
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?val=498907917&db=nuccore&dopt=fasta&extrafeat=0&fmt_mask=0&maxplex=1&sendto=t&withmarkup=on&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000
```

So, here what you should do:

```
wget "whatever" -O temp.html
id=`cat temp.html | grep ncbi_uidlist | sed -e 's/^.*ncbi_uidlist\" content=\"//' | sed -e 's/".*//'`
wget "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?val=$id&db=nuccore&dopt=fasta&extrafeat=0&fmt_mask=0&maxplex=1&sendto=t&withmarkup=on&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000"
```

Comment: @fabioln79 I know. I tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Use [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/index.html).

It has a `-dump` option which provides the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Does lynx execute JavaScript?

Comment: You can pipe HTML output to `lynx`.

Comment: Then it's no use here - data is generated in JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidJashi if you don't understand what was implied by piping HTML output to lynx, it might be better to remain silent.

Comment: I like your politeness, so I will give you polite answer too: download and look at HTML in question before telling someone to remain silent.